# expected expression before ' {' with mutexs initialize

Tags: c, struct, pthreads

I'm trying to initialize arrays of mutexes and condition variables inside a function.
The array is of type Cell which i deifined and each Cell contain mutex, condition variable and char. 
I'm getting the error on the 3 lines inside the for loop in intiail_circle:

```
expected expression before ‘{’ token.
```

I tried to initial the array also outside the function but it didn't help. any ideas what cause it?

the code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 5    
#define num_of_cells  (2*(2*N - 2))


typedef struct Generator{
    pthread_t tid;
    int id;
}Genarator;

typedef struct Car{
    pthread_t carId;
    int location ,GenID,num_of_steps;
}Car;

typedef struct Cell{
    char val;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
}Cell;

Cell circle[num_of_cells];
Cell generators_location[4];
struct Generator *generators[4];

int main(){
    initial_circle();
}

void initial_circle(){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < num_of_cells; i++){
        circle[i].mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
        circle[i].cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
        circle[i].val = ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: `Genarator`? You mean Gen**e**rator?

Comment: lol yes, thnks..any ideas about the initialization?

Comment: What is `N` supposed to be? If you look at the result of macro expansion, you will get this line: `Cell circle[(2*(2*N - 2))];` without any definition of `N` anywhere.

Comment: its  defined as 5. forgot to add it

Answer (score 4):

The macros `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` and `PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER` are initializers for a `struct`.  They look like this:

```
#define PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (void *) 0, 0, 0 } }
#define PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, __PTHREAD_SPINS, { 0, 0 } } }
```

This syntax is only valid in an initializer, not an assignment, which is why you're getting the error.

You can work around this by making a compound literal out of them:

```
    circle[i].mutex = (pthread_mutex_t)PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    circle[i].cond = (pthread_cond_t)PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

Also, you're calling the function `initial_circle` before it is declared.  You should move the definition of `initial_circle` further up in the file before `main`:

```
void initial_circle(){
    ...
}

int main(){
    initial_circle();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` is an initializer! It expands to the form `{ /*stuff*/ }`. You cannot use an initializer in assignment, an initializer has no type in C. Your problem can be reduced to this:

```
struct foo { char c; };
#define FOO_INIT { 'a' }

struct foo f =  FOO_INIT; // Okay
f = FOO_INIT; // Error
```

If you are compiling for [c99](/questions/tagged/c99) or newer, you can work around the restriction by using a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal):

```
    circle[i].mutex = (pthread_mutex_t)PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    circle[i].cond = (pthread_cond_t)PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

If c99 is not an option for you, use named objects:

```
    pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
    circle[i].mutex = mutex;
    circle[i].cond = cond;
```

Comment: its work!!thnks. but one more question..
how can I use this for array? is it will initialized automatically?
    struct foo f =  FOO_INIT; // Okay

Comment: @RoyAncri - You mean if the structure contains an array as a field? Will still work the same. But if have an array *instead* of a struct, it can't work. You can't assign to an array name.